# How to fix/setup routing from host to guest on VirtualBox?

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I am using Debian stretch to run a Debian jessie guest. I have the guest setup with a NAT and a Host-only adapter. When I try to ping my guest from my host, my ping gets routed to my wireless Internet adapter instead of the virtual network.

From `ifconfig -a`, the virtual host-only network:

```
vboxnet1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.57.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.16.255.255
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and my wireless adapter:

```
wlp4s1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::218:39ff:fe19:2edd  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:18:39:19:2e:dd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 473074  bytes 138461228 (132.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 438482  bytes 389764274 (371.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My routing table:

```
$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlp4s1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlp4s1
```

I would expect there to be some routes in `netstat -rn` directing relevant traffic to the virtual host-only nextwork, but I don't see this.

When I try to ping my guest (puffin) from my host:

```
$ ping puffin
PING puffin (172.16.57.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 1-128-201-31.ftth.glasoperator.nl (31.201.128.1) icmp_seq=1 Packet filtered
```

I have my guest's IP address (on eth1/the host-only adapter) set statically to 172.16.57.101 (and it is up) and dhcp is disabled on vboxnet1 (the host-only network).

Edit:

I found the problem with:

```
ip link
...
5: vboxnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Your `default route` is likely to go through your wireless adapter, ping can be pretty dumb at times, make sure when you ping you are specifying with `-I vboxnet1` that you are trying to use that adapter as the route to the host.

Better solution in general might be to set up a bridged connection and get rid of the NAT/Host-only all-together.

Comment: @Gravy, thanks for the tip about "-I". Apparently vboxnet1 wasn't up. I found the solution here: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=131711  and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1178607. I wanted to avoid a bridge connection because I didn't want my guest exposed (even though this is overkill on my LAN).

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it settled. If you have the chance you should transcribe those answers onto this site for record keeping/ Future searches, and then accept that answer :)

Comment: Definitely. I will need to remember to accept it in 2 days after it is allowed (unless someone writes better answer before then).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently VirtualBox wasn't able to start vboxnet0/vboxnet1, which I noticed when I did:

```
$ ping -I vboxnet1 puffin
connect: Network is unreachable
```

The problem could be found with

```
$ip link
(...)
5: vboxnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

The following fixed the issue:

```
sudo ip link up vboxnet1
```

And now I get:

```
$ip link
(...)
5: vboxnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:00:27:00:00:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

More details can be found:

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=131711
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1178607